# Slider going all the way down the page on certain frames

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, plugins

I don't know what is going on, but I have a nivoslider on my Wordpress website, and on certain slides (only uses two different images), the slider seems to show one of the slider images going all the way down the page, like it is 100px wide and 1000px height.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, I can post specific code if needed, let me know, here is the website:-

http://krystalsmoke.co.uk/

Let me know if you need me to paste any of the code behind this.

Answer (score 0):

Post the code and I will see if I can help...

also, did you check your image sizes and I presume you have them in a DIV when inside the slider - so check that size too..

I had this issue once and it was caused by one image not been found. This threw off the entire slider, which too went all over the page. So, check the link to the image  and make sure images are good size

Comment: Background images look okay, there are only two; http://krystalsmoke.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/81.png and http://krystalsmoke.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/7.png - I can post the code now, but there are quite a few files for the nivoslider

Comment: can't post the code today, waiting for the guy to provide me with the ftp details so I can post the code, can't access /js from control panel.